# Proof of the Abel's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Abel's lemma is given in Abbott's Understanding Analysis as follows:

> Let $b_n$ satisfy $b_1 \geq b_2 \geq ...\geq 0$ and let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ be a series for which the partial sums are bounded. In other words, assume there exists $A>0$ such that $|a_1+a_2+...+a_n| \leq A$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Then, for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $|a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n| \leq 2Ab_1$.

The proof is not given but it is said that the proof follows from the **summation by parts**. I found [here](http://pirate.shu.edu/%7Ewachsmut/ira/numser/proofs/sumparts.html) that the summation by parts is:

> Consider two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$. Let $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$ be the n-th partial sum. Then for any $0 \leq m \leq n$ we have
>
> $$\sum_{j=m}^na_jb_j=[S_nb_n-S_{m-1}b_m]+\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}S_j(b_j-b_{j+1})$$

Applying the above definition to Abel's lemma gives:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jb_j=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(b_j-b_{j+1})S_j+S_nb_n-S_0b_1$$

But I am stuck here. I don't know the value of $S_0$ and I can't see a way to find $2Ab_1$ part of the Abel's lemma. Can you show me what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $S_0 = 0$. Then, since $|S_j| \leqslant A$ and $b_j - b_{j+1} \geqslant 0,$ we can conclude

$$\left| \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} ( b_j - b_{j+1} ) S_j + S_n b_n \right| \leqslant |S_n| \cdot b_n + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} ( b_j - b_{j+1} ) \cdot |S_j| \leqslant A \cdot b_n + A \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} ( b_j - b_{j+1} ).$$

Terms under sum will cancel out, giving:

$$A \cdot b_n + A \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} ( b_j - b_{j+1} ) = A \cdot \left[ b_n + ( b_1 - b_n)\right] = A b_1.$$

We actually acquired a stricter bound.

Comment: Do we take $S_0=0$ because it is undefined? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Nope, it follows from the formula: if $n = 0$ in $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n a_j$, then the sum has zero summands, so it's zero. If you don't feel convinced, try proving the summation by parts formula for this special case and you'll see how it works.