# Abel's inequality and lower bound of inner product.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

Consider Able's inequality, $ \sum_{i} a_i b_i \le (\max_r\vert \sum_{i=1}^rb_i\vert) (\vert a_n \vert+a_n-a_1)$, where the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a non-decreasing sequence. [Abel's Inequality, wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_inequality)

Question:

1- How to prove this inequality?

Edit: I found the answer to this question on site, in [Abel's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276815/proof-of-the-abels-lemma?rq=1), not exactly the same but it suffices. No need to answer this question any more.

2- If $b_i>=0$, and $\sum_{i} a_i b_i \gt 0 $, what is a positive lower bound for $\sum_{i} a_i b_i$ ? Is it tight?
All of the values are real.

My Guess: Consider $ \sum_{i} a_i b_i \ge (\max_r\vert \sum_{i=1}^rb_i\vert) (2a_{+}-a_1)$, where $a_{+}=\min_{i,a_i>0} a_i$. Is this inequality correct?
This inequality incorrect according to a deleted answer by NP_Hard. But is there a positive lower bound?

Comment: I delete my answer and hope for a better one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Are $a_i$'s non-negative?

Comment: In order to have a non-trivial lower bound, you should impose some additional conditions on $a_i$’s and $b_$’s, otherwise a tight lower bound is $0$ even when all $a_i$’s and $b_i$’s are positive, because for an arbitrarily large natural $n$ we can put all $a_i$’s are equal to $1/n$ and all $b_i$’s are $1$.